# I want to edit the button text inside this id "product_info"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, datatables, min.js

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <strong>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          <span>Add Sale</span>
       </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post" action="add_sale.php">
         <table class="table table-bordered">
           <thead>
            <th> Item </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Qty </th>
            <th> Total </th>
            <th> Date</th>
            <th> Action</th>
           </thead>
             <tbody id="product_info" > </tbody>
         </table>
       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to do script function still doesn't apply and changes the text of the button. Ive tried variety of codes just to change it but seems like all are not working.

[image]

Comment: James, can you update your question with more details? Currently, this tag with id "product_info" is empty. You're saying you have button there and you want to change its text?

Could you show the Javascript code you're using to make this work?

Comment: To be honest Im still new about javascript and the script I use are connected online so I dont know how to change it.. I think this is bootstrap .. I dont know but I can show you this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xefpv.jpg -- In the left is my code and there is nothing to it that I can edit inside the id. So yes I want to change the button text there, This is the script I use  type="text/javascript" src="libs/js/functions.js"> I hope you understand my english

Comment: Hey, you're doing fine, don't worry about your english. If you want to change the button text, take a look at this picture you sent. On the lower, right side of it, there's a text in white that says "Add sale". if you change that text, the button text is going to change

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example is all HTML. You have not posted any of your JavaScript Code. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The right side code is actually from web inspect, the code that I used is on the top and thats just it .. <tbody id="productinfo"> </tbody> and I dont have javascript codes, because it was taken online

Comment: This is the script that is connected to that id and I cant edit it, I dont know how <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Its ok now guys, thank you.. I found the solution.